Discrete Poisson Equation within soft region
I am looking for guidance on how I could implement the Discrete Poisson Equation for the task of image seamless cloning in non-binary regions. Normally the equation is solved inside a binary region: 1 inside 0 outside (Equation 4 of this paper). In this case, I know how to define the boundary conditions and solve the $Ax = b$ system.
However, if the region is a non-binary region. How would one build the matrix $A$ and vector $b$? Does this even make sense and would it have any benefit over the binary version?

due to linearity, the sum of two solutions will solve for the sum of the bc

Sorry I am not following. You mean I need to solve to $Ax=b$ systems?

i mean, if you can write the new b.c. in terms of a sum of 1,0 b.c. you can probably get a solution that is a sum of the per boundary solutions
